# Most pythonic way to process this text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file containg test data that looks like:

```
hdr 1

hdr2

hdr3

data1

data2

data3

data1

data2

....
```

There is a blank line between every line.

I need to create a list of lists containing

```
[[hdr1,hdr2,hdr3],[data1,data2,data3],[data1,data2,...]
```

What would be a concise, pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: What is the rule that determines where one group ends and the next begins?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your data will always be in blocks of 3 like in your example, you could probably use `itertools`, and if you pass the same iterator 6 times then you should end up with 6 fields, 3 of them the empty lines, and the other ones the group of 3 you're interested in:

```
import itertools

arr = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for field1,blank1,field2,blank2,field3,blank3 in itertools.izip_longest(*[f]*6):
        arr.append([field1,field2,field3])
```

(inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1657385/1332690))

**EDIT**: You may need to call `strip()` on the fields so as to not include any extra \n, so `arr.append([field1.strip(),field2.strip(),field3.strip()])`

Comment: +1. I'd write it in terms of `grouper` (from the itertools recipes in the docs) rather than explicitly zipping `*[f]*6`, because that's pretty hard for most people to understand in the middle of a complex line. Also, you don't need to explicitly throw out the blank lines; just use `[::2]`. So, you can replace everything but the `with` line with `arr = [group[::2] for group in grouper(6, f)]`.

Comment: For the sake of pythonicity, I'd do: `arr.append(map(lambda x:x.strip(), [field1, field2, field3])`, but that surely is a bit overkill... :P

Comment: @heltonbiker: I don't think using `map` with a `lambda` makes things more Pythonic than either using a list comprehension or `map` with `str.strip`. But agreed that it's probably more Pythonic than doing it explicitly on three values—especially if you're using a slice or a `filter` to get those values.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a simplified version of Charles Menguy's solution, and I'm only adding it as an answer because it was hard to read as a comment. But here's the key:

First, use `grouper` from the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to group the file into groups of 6 lines:

```
groups = grouper(6, f)
```

Next, you can throw out every other line just by slicing:

```
nonblank = [group[::2] for group in groups]
```

Or, alternatively, by filtering out the blank lines explicitly:

```
nonblank = [filter(bool, group) for group in groups]
```

If you need to strip each line, you can either use a list comprehension, or `map`. Generally, I prefer `map` if I don't need to lambda/partial up a new function, and here we don't; it's just `map(str.strip, group)`.

Putting it together, here's the whole thing, as a one-liner (which I think is still pretty readable):

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    arr = [map(str.strip, group[::2]) for group in grouper(6, f)]
```

Comment: Nice abstraction on top of `izip_longest` ! You got my vote for finding a way to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is the best solution or how much is it pythonic, but you can simply use regular expressions to parse the lines of your file:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s*(\d+)')
last_groups = None
group = []
data = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = regex.search(line)
        if match:
            if last_groups is None:
                last_groups = match.groups()

            if last_groups[0] == match.groups()[0] and \
                    int(last_groups[1]) <= int(match.groups()[1]):
                last_groups = match.groups()
                group.append(''.join(last_groups))
            else:
                data.append(group)
                last_groups = match.groups()
                group = [''.join(last_groups)]

if group:
    data.append(group)
```