# Python: Read multiple lines from a file and make instances stored in an dictionary

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, readline

### My struggle:

#### Reading two lines and jumping over the third.

Then I want to store all the objects in a dictionary with the name as keys.

```
**** Ingredients.txt ****
Name1
ingredient1/ingredient2/ingredient3

Name2
ingredient1/ingredient2

Name3
...
```

```
class Foodset(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.ingredients = set([])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ' consits of: ' + ", ".join(str(e) for e in self.ingredients) + '.'

    def setIngredients(self, list):
        for i in list:
            self.ingredients.add(i)

def getMenu(file="ingredients.txt"):
    with open(file, 'r') as indata:
        menu = dict()
        for line in indata:
            tempString = str(line.rstrip('\n'))
            menu[tempString] = Foodset(tempString)
```

I want to read the next line and store as ingredients and then skip the third line since it's blank. Then repeat.

The problem I'm having with the for loop is that I can't store two different lines in the same loop and then refer to the same object in order to use the setIngredients() method. **What other ways can I read multiple lines inside each loop?**

EDIT:
@Arpan came up with a quick solution to use indata.readlines() to make a list of every line and loop with steps of 3 while storing first and second value and skipping the third.

**I just came up with an other solution** using the **readline() method 3 times** inside a while loop. Using readline() is what I originally wanted.

```
def getMenu(menu="ingredients.txt"):
    with open(menu, "r") as indata:
        menu = dict()
        while True:
            name = indata.readline().strip('\n')
            ingredientList = indata.readline().strip().split('/')
            if name == "":
                break
# here I just added a parameter that directly set the attribute "ingredients" inside the object.
            menu[name] = Foodset(name, ingredientList)
            indata.readline()
    return menu
```

Comment: This is many questions in one. Can you please isolate the problem? Is reading the file the problem, is getting three lines at once the problem? Is building your custom object the problem? If you edit your question to just contain a minimal example of the part you are struggling with, you will get help faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
with open(file, 'r') as indata:
    lines = indata.readlines()
menu = dict()
for i in xrange(0, len(lines), 3):
    name = lines[i].rstrip('\n')
    ingredients = lines[i+1].rstrip('\n').split('/')
    f = Foodset(name)
    f.setIngredients(ingredients)
    menu[name] = f
```

For python 3.x use `range` instead of `xrange`.

Comment: So making a list and using index seems to be a solution. Why use xrange? (I'm trying this right now)

Comment: Using range generates a list with all the objects, whereas using xrange is a sequence object that evaluates lazily.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x

Comment: okey, that was perfect. Very simple and easy to use. I'll slim down my question to make it easier for others to understand. My first question to Stack Overflow so thanks for understanding the problem and quickly solving it. Do I just click the "solved" check mark and you get the point?

Comment: You're welcome @TheRawPerformer . You can click the upvote button as well if you liked the answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to upvote since I don't have any reputation points yet. Does it show that your answer solved my question?

Comment: Accepting the answer shows that it solved your problem the best among the others, upvoting shows that you like the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can read three lines at once using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
import itertools
with open('ingredients.txt') as f:
    while True:
        next_three_lines = list(itertools.islice(f, 3))
        if not next_three_lines:
            break
        else:
            print next_three_lines
```

In your case this will print

```
['Name1\n', 'ingredient1/ingredient2/ingredient3\n', '\n']
['Name2\n', 'ingredient1/ingredient2\n', '\n']
['Name3\n', '...']
```

Then you can change the print line to `rstrip('\n')` and use the first two elements of each `next_three_lines` to build your object:

```
tempString = str(next_three_lines[0].rstrip('\n'))
menu[tempString] = Foodset(tempString)
menu[tempString].setIngredients(next_three_lines[1].rstrip('\n').split('/')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll definitely keep this method in mind since it seems very useful and clean. +1

Answer (score 0):

I will show you a way to parse your file. Building a dictionary from the dishes and their ingredients is the simple part, so I will leave that to you.

Demo file input.txt:

```
Name1
ingredient1/ingredient2/ingredient3

Name2
ingredient1/ingredient2

Name3
ingredient1/ingredient2/ingredient3
```

Code:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

with open('input.txt') as infile:
    for name, ingr, _ in izip_longest(*[infile]*3, fillvalue='\n'):
        ingredients = ingr.split('/')
        print name.strip()
        for ing in ingredients:
            print ing.strip()
        print
```

Output:

```
Name1
ingredient1
ingredient2
ingredient3

Name2
ingredient1
ingredient2

Name3
ingredient1
ingredient2
ingredient3
```

Explanation:

`infile` is an iterator, which is passed three times to `izip_longest`, so each iteration `izip_longest` will call `next` on the same iterator three times. I use an empty line as the `fillvalue` argument in case your file does not end with an empty line.

Splitting the string with the ingredients by the `'/'` character will give you a list of ingredients.

There's more explanation/information and also some alternatives on how to read multiple lines from a file at once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657299/how-do-i-read-two-lines-from-a-file-at-a-time-using-python).