# How to properly build a dictionary when .txt file has the key and values on pairs of consecutive lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Code:

```
trans_file = open("textabbv.txt", "r")
def text_translate(user_input):
    user_input = input("Please enter your text: ")  
    textdict = {}
    for line in trans_file:
        readline(line)
        line = line.split(":")
        line = line.strip('\n')
```

Contents of textabbv.txt:

> r:
>   are
>   y:
>   why
>   u:
>   you
>   ttyl:
>   talk to you later
>   l8:
>   late
>   brb:
>   be right back
>   lol:
>   laughing out loud
>   bbl:
>   be back later
>   tl;dr:
>   too long; didn't read
>   rofl:
>   rolling on floor laughing
>   gtg:
>   got to go
>   cya:
>   see you
>   cuzz:
>   because
>   bff:
>   best friend forever
>   bffs:
>   best friends forever
>   idk:
>   I don't know
>   sup:
>   what's up?
>   omg:
>   oh my gosh
>   nbd:
>   no big deal
>   tisnf:
>   this is not fair
>   nw:
>   no way!
>   rus:
>   are you serious?
>   myob:
>   mind your own business
>   njoy:
>   enjoy
>   nter:
>   enter
>   1ce:
>   once
>   aka:
>   also known as
>   afk:
>   away from keyboard
>   jk:
>   just kidding
>   asap:
>   as soon as possible
>   app:
>   application
>   atm:
>   at the moment
>   b4:
>   before
>   fyi:
>   for your information
>   bday:
>   birthday
>   k:
>   okay
>   msg:
>   message
>   np:
>   no problem
>   pic:
>   picture
>   plz:
>   please
>   sry: sorry
>   dunno:
>   don't know
>   @:
>   at
>   wut:
>   what
>   wuts:
>   what's

Comment: I realize you're also new to SO, but this is a bad question - that's why it's getting downvotes. Please post a small portion of your text file and your source code directly into your question instead of linking to it on a third-party site in image format. Anyone trying to test your code would have to manually type it all for no good reason.

Comment: I'm sorry I will do that

Comment: Is the last line of your txt file `brb:`?

Comment: Hi everyone, I am writing a function with def, so can we please refrain from using with?

Comment: @AmyLee Don't change your question to a different one, after you've got an answer to the initial version.

Comment: @AmyLee Try the solutions you got here, and then you can spend some effort to change them removing the `with` keyword if you don't like it, or (better) try to understand it. SO (and the internet) is full of explanations of this keyword.

Comment: The with statement will automatically close your file when the block of code is completed.  If you don't want to use it, don't forget to close your file when you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you to so much to everyone who answered my question, I will take these comments and continue on my code.

Comment: @AmyLee Cheers and good luck! If you're stuck again, and can't find an answer amongst the existing posts on SO, you can always post another question :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem basically boils down to reading two lines at a time, which has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657299/how-do-i-read-two-lines-from-a-file-at-a-time-using-python). So the solution for your file is:

```
import pprint

def text_translate():
    result = {}
    with open('textabbv.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            key = line.strip().strip(':')
            value = f.next().strip()
            result[key] = value
    return result

abbrvs = text_translate() 
pprint.pprint(abbrvs)
```

with `next(f)` instead of `next` for Python 3.

Note that if there is odd number of lines in the file, `f.next()` will raise a `StopIteration` exception, which should be handled explicitly in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
abbvs = []
with open("textabbv.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().strip(":")
        abbvs.append(line)

pairs = dict([tuple(abbvs[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(abbvs), 2)])

print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
{'l8': 'late', 'r': 'are', 'ttyl': 'talk to you later', 'u': 'you', 'y': 'why'}
```

If you don't want to use `with`, just do this:

```
abbvs = []
for line in open("textabbv.txt").readlines():
    line = line.strip().strip(":")
    abbvs.append(line)

pairs = dict([tuple(abbvs[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(abbvs), 2)])
print(pairs)
```

Can even do this to handle uneven lines in files:

```
try:
    abbvs = []
    with open("textabbv.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().strip(":")
            abbvs.append(line)

    pairs = dict([tuple(abbvs[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(abbvs), 2)])

    print(pairs)

except ValueError:
    print("Uneven number of lines in txt file found")
```

Comment: I get this error...
builtins.ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: @Amina This most probably means an error in the text file (most of time there's something wrong with the last entry).

Comment: Yeah I made another text file with the picture you posted, which was all I could see. Can you show the whole picture of it @Amina?

Comment: I will post a picture

Comment: Yeah Just post the whole thing, so we can see exactly what's in there.

Comment: Yeah this should work if for every key, there is a value.

Comment: I posted everything including my code and the .txt file so you can see everything

Comment: Yeah there was something wrong with your text file, One line had `sry: sorry`, which will make the code not work as there will be an uneven number of lines. Make sure that line is separated, and then run the code again, it should work.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much...I am not familiar with the "with" that you have in your code, what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Yeah `with` just makes sure that your file will get closed, it stops you from going `file.close()` everytime you want to close a file. Just a fool proof method of handling files. A good explanation can be found here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @AmyLee if you liked this answer then mark it as correct :)

Comment: Sorry @RoadRunner I liked it just now! :)

Comment: Thanks @AmyLee, I hoped this help a bit. If you still need some more help just let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a quick oneliner:

```
>>> f = open(r"c:/tests/test.txt", "r")
>>> xlines = iter(f.readlines())
>>> {k.rstrip("\n").rstrip(":"):v.strip("\n") for k, v in zip(xlines,xlines)}
{'pic': 'picture', 'np': 'no problem', 'aka': 'also known as', 'k': 'okay', 'nw': 'no way!', 'sry: sorry': 'dunno:', 'myob': 'mind your own business', 'bffs': 'best friends forever', 'afk': 'away from keyboard', 'tisnf': 'this is not fair', '1ce': 'once', 'jk': 'just kidding', 'tl;dr': "too long; didn't read", 'ttyl': 'talk to you later', 'bff': 'best friend forever', 'asap': 'as soon as possible', 'njoy': 'enjoy', 'nter': 'enter', 'r': 'are', 'atm': 'at the moment', 'what': 'wuts:', 'gtg': 'got to go', 'cuzz': 'because', 'cya': 'see you', 'rofl': 'rolling on floor laughing', 'app': 'application', 'u': 'you', 'y': 'why', 'lol': 'laughing out loud', 'nbd': 'no big deal', 'brb': 'be right back', 'bbl': 'be back later', 'b4': 'before', 'omg': 'oh my gosh', 'fyi': 'for your information', 'at': 'wut:', 'rus': 'are you serious?', 'l8': 'late', 'msg': 'message', 'sup': "what's up?", "don't know": '@:', 'plz': 'please', 'idk': "I don't know", 'bday': 'birthday'}
```