# Reading next line of big text file

Tags: python, file, iteration

I'm new to python. I have a huge text file (about 15gb), so it is not possible to read in all the lines, I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into) how to fix that problem. Now about my problem. Is it possible to read the next line within a for loop without jumping to the beginning of the loop.

This is what I mean

```
with open(input) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print("current line: ",line)
        #reading next line
        print("this is the second line ", line)
        #jumping back to the beginning and working with the 3rd line
```

When my text looks like this.

```
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
4th line
5th line
6th line
7th line
```

I want the output to be like this

```
current line: 1st line
this is the second line: 2nd line
current line: 3rd line
this is the second line: 4th line
...
```

Comment: did you run your code? what happens?

Comment: @Psytho The code I posted always outputs the same line until the for loop starts over, which is logical. I have commented what I want in the code

Comment: So you basically want to loop through 2 lines at once? 1-2, 3-4 (always pairs)... or 1-2, 2-3 (always previous and current)...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657299/how-do-i-read-two-lines-from-a-file-at-a-time-using-python Here is how to always loop in pairs (1-2, 3-4, 5-6...) - I'd recommend second answer, with itertools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read two lines from a file at a time using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657299/how-do-i-read-two-lines-from-a-file-at-a-time-using-python)

Comment: @h4z3 I want it to be possible to read in the next line three times or four times. For example `jumpToNextLine() if line == "3rd line"`.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to read a variable number of lines each time? Then top answer from the linked question is actually good as you just do `while True` and get lines inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an `iter()` and `next()`.

```py
with open('text.txt') as infile:
    iterator = iter(infile)
    for line in iterator:
        print("current line:",line)
        print("this is the second line", next(iterator, "End of File"))
```

Given the input file:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

it outputs:

```sh
current line: A
this is the second line B
current line: C
this is the second line D
current line: E
this is the second line End of File
```

Comment: You do 1-2, 2-3, while OP's example shows iterating in pairs: 1-2, 3-4 :)

Comment: @h4z3 the post got updated right after I posted my answer :)

Comment: You solved my problem thank you very much