# Is possible to iterate file by two lines?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [reading lines 2 at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528711/reading-lines-2-at-a-time)

In python we can iterate over file line by line. But what if i want iterate by two lines?

```
f = open("filename")
for line1, line2 in ?? f ??:
    do_stuff(line1, line2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
with open('myFile.txt') as fh:
  for line1 in fh:
    line2 = next(fh)

    # Code here can use line1 and line2.
```

You may need to watch for a `StopIteration` error on the call to `next(fh)` if you have odd lines.  The solutions with `izip_longest` are probably better able to avoid that need.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `grouper` function from the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes).

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


f = open(filename)
for line1, line2 in grouper(2, f):
    print('A:', line1, 'B:', line2)
```

Use `zip` instead of `zip_longest` to ignore an odd line at the end.

The `zip_longest` function was named `izip_longest` in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open("file")
content = f.readlines()
print content[0] #You can choose lines from a list.
print content[1]
```

This is one way to do it. Now you can just iterate through the list with a for-loop and do whatever you want with it, or choose lines explicitly.

Comment: This will read the entire file into memory at once.  That may not be a great idea.