# reading and checking the consecutive words in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to read the words in a file, and say for example, check if the word is "1",if word is 1, I have to check if the next word is "two". After that i have to do some other task. Can u help me to check the occurance of "1" and "two" consecutively.

I have used

```
filne = raw_input("name of existing file to be proceesed:")
f = open(filne, 'r+')
for word in f.read().split():
    for i in xrange(len(word)):
        print word[i]
        print word[i+1]
```

but its not working.

Comment: You need to put a bit more effort in here, have you tried or thought about how to approach this? Are you going to map digits to their alphanumeric equivalent and is this mapping only ever `1 -> two` or is `One -> two` also possible?

Comment: You're just printing the word. Why did you think it would work?

Comment: I want to check if the first word is "1" numerical and if the next word "kodi" which is crore in tamil.

Comment: actually am printing the words just to check if the words are traversed or not

Comment: @EdChum : i always want to check if 1st word is "1" and the second is either கோடி or லட்சம் i.e., crore or lakh in tamil

Comment: @user3003478 ok but your code doesn't show any of this comparison check, the point being show us what you've done and where you are stuck. The SO community is not here to code this for you, only to solve specific problems.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik : i tried to check if the numbers are getting traversed or not.

Comment: what is the problem? is there an exception or is the output not what you expected it to be?

Comment: @RajivNair : Contents of my file : hello testing. 
100 கோடி , 1 கோடி. I get the following in the terminal :name of existing file to be proceesed:en3
h
e
e
l
l
l
l
o
o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 17, in <module>
    print word[i+1]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @RajivNair: I guess the word[i] reads the word like an array traversal, but i want to traverse to next word.

Comment: @EdChum : I just want to know how to check the consecutive words. if there is any inbuilt functions for it. I am just trying that. I have not developed any program as of now. Am a beginner so I thought may be SO community will help me know it. Thanks for ur reply. Apologies for not being specific.

Comment: You need to post the raw data and error traceback results. One approach once you get over your initial hurdle is to store a lookup table, probably a dict so that you can compare the tamil against the numeric value.

Comment: Your question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528711/reading-lines-2-at-a-time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with consecutive items is with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f: # better way to open file   
    for line in f: # for each line
        words = line.strip().split() # all words on the line
        for word1, word2 in zip(words, words[1:]): # iterate through pairs
            if word1 == '1' and word2 == 'crore': # test the pair
```

At the moment, your indices (`i` and `i+1`) are within each word (i.e. characters) not for words within the list.

Comment: Thanx 4 helping out! i juzt added if word1 == '1': (nested) if word2 == 'crore', print yes. and my document has 2 instances of such an occurance, but it prints yes only once. can u tell me why it is so? thanx in advance.

Comment: Not sure without seeing the input data. If you have more than one line of input, note that this will only process the first line. Also, you can do `if word1 == '1' and word2 == 'crore':` rather than the nested test.

Comment: yes. My input is of 3lines, as follows:"1 crore rupees.
its good.1 crore." How do i process the full file, is there eof checking function in python, like how we have in c and c++ . (if eof())

Comment: I have updated my example, assuming that you want to process each line separately.

Comment: I want to split the character and number separately from the word, example ரூ100, how to split 'ரூ' and '100' or Rs100, how to split 'Rs' and '100'.

Comment: @charvi I suggest you look into python's various [string methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: @jonrsharpe  can u help with this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777092/how-to-replace-only-certain-words-in-a-file

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to print two consecutive words from the file,
In your code you are iterating over the each character instead of each word in file if thats what you intend to do.
You can do that in following way:

```
f = open('yourFileName')
str1 = f.read().split()
for i in xrange(len(str1)-1): # -1 otherwise it will be index out of range error 
    print str1[i]
    print str1[i+1]
```

and if you want to check some word is present and want check for word next to it, use

```
if 'wordYouWantToCheck' in str1:
    index=str1.index('wordYouWantToCheck')
```

Now you have index for the word you are looking for, you can check for the word next to it using `str1[index+1]`.

But 'index' function will return only the first occurrence of the word. To accomplish your intent here, you can use 'enumerate' function.

```
indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(str1) if x == "1"]
```

This will return list containing indices of all occurrences of word '1'.

Comment: Thank u for giving the logic. It checks the consecutive words now. I tried like u said, my code:                                          filename = raw_input("name of file:")
f = open(filename, 'r+')
str1=f.read().split()
for i in xrange(len(str1)-1): 
 if '1' in str1:
  index=str1.index('1')
  if "crore" in str1[index+1]:
   print "yes" . Now in my file i have the following contents : 1 crore rupees.
its good.
1 crore. it should print "yes" only twice. but it prints it 6 times which am not able to understand.

Comment: You don't have to use for loop, when you don't want to print the consecutive names. You can directly check the word in list.`filename = raw_input("name of file:") f = open(filename, 'r+') str1=f.read().split() if '1' in str1: index=str1.index('1') if "crore" in str1[index+1]: print "yes" `

Comment: But 'index' function will return only the first occurrence of the word. To accomplish your intent here, you can use 'enumerate' function. `indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(str1) if x == "1"]` This will return indices of all occurrences of word '1'.