# how to replace only certain words in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

This program is to check if two specific words(ex: 'ஒன்று' and 'கோடி' ) occur consecutively and if so replace the first word with a particular word(ex: 'ஒரு'). I have to read the contents from a file and write them into another. I have used a flag variable, initialized from 2,and am printing into file only when flag%2==0, so that the words are not repeated into the new file. The pgm works only when the words are in even places, it doesn't work otherwise. How should i change the checking and printing. Here is the code:

```
filename = raw_input("enter file:")
ff = open(filename+'.rep_out','w')
with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
    for line in f:
        words = line.strip().split() 
        flag = 2
        for word1, word2 in zip(words, words[1:]): 
            if flag%2 == 0:
                if word1 == 'ஒன்று' or word1 == '1':
                    if word2 == 'கோடி'  or word2 == 'லட்சம்' or word2 == 'ஆயிரம்' :
                        #word1=word1.replace(word1,'ஒரு')
                        word1='ஒரு'
                        #ff.write(word1+" ")
                ff.write(word1+" ")
                ff.write(word2+" ")             
            flag=flag+1
f.close()
ff.close()
```

Comment: `ஒரு ஆயிரம்` won't be correct right? `ஓராயிரம்`?

Comment: @thefourtheye : i want the replacement some how, atleast the meaning will remain the same. can u help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your string manipulations get this complex, there's a good chance you can do better with a more powerful tool than Python's string methods. In this case, it is quite a bit easier to use regular expressions:

```
import re

with open(filename) as f:
   with open(filename + '.rep_out') as ff:
       for line in f:
          ff.write(re.sub("ஒன்று (கோடி|லட்சம்|ஆயிரம்)", r"ஒரு \1", line))
```

explanation:

the regex `"ஒன்று (கோடி|லட்சம்|ஆயிரம்)"` matches any occurrence of ஒன்று followed consecutively by any of கோடி, லட்சம் or ஆயிரம் - you can extend that to as many candidate second words as you need to.

[re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) replaces that with the replacement first word (ஒரு), followed by the *same* second word that it found before - the \1 tells it "put the bit that matched the first set of () back in here" (that \1 is why it needs to be a raw string - you want that parsed by re.sub, not by Python's string literal rules).

As written, the above code assumes words on each line are separated by exactly one space, which is different from your original code that allows them to be separated by any amount of whitespace, but would *output* them separated by a single space. To match that behaviour, you can modify the regex above like so:

```
 re.sub("ஒன்று\s+(கோடி|லட்சம்|ஆயிரம்)", r"ஒரு \1", line)
```

The \s matches any whitespace character, and the + means "match multiples of that in a row, as long as there is at least one".

Note that when you use `with open(...) as f:`, you don't need to call `f.close()` afterwards - that happens automatically when you exit the `with` block.

Comment: are only the above lines enough?? or should i put anything more?? coz i tried and i did not work.

Comment: @charvi you would need to replace 'word1' with your actual word1 (ie, 'ஒன்று'), and similar with all of the word2s - it doesn't do any kind of variable substitution. I've updated my answer to make this a bit clearer. Other than that, it should work. What output do you get?

Comment: I had tried that only, It did not replace. I tried again also, it does not replace it.

Comment: @charvi so, to be clear, the output you get matches the input exactly?

Comment: yes. there is no change at all. input file and output file are same.

Comment: @charvi the only thing I can think of is that my code requires exactly a space between words, while your original code accepts any amount of whitespace. I've added an explanation of how to change that.

Comment: it works now.... i dint know that whitespace could be a problem in processing. Thanks for your efforts!!! thank u !!

Comment: can u tell me what to do if i have to check for pairs like : ரூபாய் கோடி,ரூபாய் லட்சம் and ரூபாய் ஆயிரம். If its present replace as கோடி ரூபாய், லட்சம் ரூபாய் and ஆயிரம் ரூபாய் correspondingly.

Comment: @charvi for that, you could do something like `re.sub("(ரூபாய்)\s+கோடி", r"கோடி \1", line)`. If you reassign that result back to `line` instead of writing it out, you can run several of these filters in a row - although if you have more than a few of them, it might be worth looking into whether more advanced uses of `re.sub` (with a function instead of a string as its second argument) might serve you better.